# problems running vssadmin from c#

Tags: c#

I am executing the following code from C#

```
Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=10%")
            {
                WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }
        };
        
        process.OutputDataReceived += (object _sender, DataReceivedEventArgs _e) => Console.WriteLine("output :: " + _e.Data);

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (object _sender, DataReceivedEventArgs _e) => Console.WriteLine("error :: " + _e.Data);

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", process.ExitCode);
        process.Close();
```

and it shows me the following error

> "vssadmin" is not recognized as an internal or external command

but if I execute that line from the command console it works correctly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Z2H.png)

How can I execute that code from c#?
Regards!

Comment: Can't you just start vssadmin.exe directly instead of cmd.exe? vssadmin.exe is in system32 so with a bit of luck it will start, if not give it the full path.

Comment: Specify vassadmin.exe as the file to run rather than cmd.exe - `new ProcessStartInfo("vssadmin", "help")` works for me, as does fully specifying the path as suggested by @rene

Comment: @stuartd I did it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @EdsonOrdaz please tell us what you did that didn’t work

Comment: still doesn't work